# Run terminal commands on PHP with CENTOS

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have no idea why the code below does not work:

```
<?php shell_exec('pkill -x firefox') ?>
```

I am not running PHP in safe_mode, the fucntion shell_exec is enabled to be used so WHY my apache is not killink firefox?

Comment: do I need to run apache not as a service to kill/start a program?

Comment: smells like a user permission issue

Comment: I already added the code to sudoers:    apache ALL=(ALL) ALL    and still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't run firefox with apache user, you can't kill that process using apache. You have to run apache as root to access all processes in system.

Warning: Running any public service with root permissions is a serious security risk.

Answer (score 0):

That is because apache runs as either `www-data` or `nobody` user and because of this, it you can't kill that process because that user doesn't have sufficient enough privileges required. However, if you were to run the code as the superuser, it is possible.

```
% cat my_script.php
<?php shell_exec('pkill -x firefox') ?>
% sudo php my_script.php
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much but when I use sudo I should be able to exec the command isnt? Why this does not work: shell_exec('echo "pass" | sudo -u root -S pkill -x firefox')